# Grails : How to migrate dependencies upgrading from 2.x.x to 3.0.8?

Tags: grails

I am attempting to upgrade an existing Grails application from version **2.4.4** to **3.0.8**.  I have a couple issues that I am currently unable to resolve.

**First issue:** The old version's `BuildConfig.groovy` referenced a jar file that was in the lib directory.  I tried copying the same configuration from `BuildConfig.groovy` to `build.gradle` and created a lib directory with the jar but Grails is unable to resolve the dependency.

**Second issue:** The old version had a plugin defined.  I tried copying the same plugin definition from `BuildConfig.groovy` into `build.gradle`, but this isn't working.  I noticed that the plugin isn't currently listed in Bintray, is this the problem?

Below is the dependency section of the `build.gradle` file.

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"

    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"

    compile "com.stripe:stripe-java:1.32.1"
    compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1"
    compile "javax.mail:mail:1.4"

    runtime "org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline"

    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"

    // Note: It is recommended to update to a more robust driver (Chrome, Firefox etc.)
    testRuntime 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.44.0'

    console "org.grails:grails-console"

    //jar file located in lib directory
    runtime "com.easypost:easypost-java:2.1.2"

    //grails plugin
    compile ":shiro:1.2.1"
}
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance provided.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue 1**: If that jar is a standard jar and you can reference it from maven then that would be good. But still if you need to include it from some local directory then you can do this:

```
repositories {
   flatDir {
       //Directory path containing Jar
       dirs 'libs'
   }
}


dependencies {
   //Jar File Name - No need to add suffix .jar
   compile name: 'someJarFile'
}
```

**Issue 2**: If the plugin is not listed in bintray then that means it has not been upgraded for Grails 3.x. Either you can upgrade it for yourself or remove the plugin if possible.